# unable to manipulate a string in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, express, ejs

I have passed a JSON string to my EJS page but it shows me the string with inverted commas. I want to remove the **inverted comma** and covert it to **UPPERCASE** string. How can I do this?

```
app.get('/ranking/:category', (req, res) => {
    var category = req.params.category;
    var allCategory = ['webDesigning', 'webDevelopment']
    if (category !== undefined) {
        for(var i = 0; i < allCategory.length; i++) {
            if (allCategory[i] === category) {
                res.render('ranking', { name: category })
            }
        }
    }else {
        res.render('404');
    }
})
```

In EJS I am trying to access category like this.

```
<h1><%= JSON.stringify(name) %></h1>
```

expected output is this

**Web Designing**

Answer (score 0):

Well, `name` is a string. You can just display it. If you do `JSON.stringify(name)`, you will get `"something"`. That's the JSON representation of the string.

Second thing: if you want to transform your camelCase into separate words with capitalized first letters, you could do this like this:

```js
const camelCaseToSeparate = (camelCased) => {
  const withAddedSpaces = camelCased.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1');
  return withAddedSpaces.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + withAddedSpaces.substr(1);
};

console.log(camelCaseToSeparate('webDevelopment'));
```